# How to split a pandas dataframe into many columns after groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I want to be able to use groupby in pandas to group the data by a column, but then split it so each group is its own column in a dataframe.

e.g.:

```
   time  data
 0    1   2.0
 1    2   3.0
 2    3   4.0
 3    1   2.1
 4    2   3.1
 5    3   4.1
 etc.
```

into

```
       data1  data2  ... dataN
 time  
 1     2.0      2.1  ...
 2     3.0      3.1  ...
 3     4.0      4.1  ...
```

I am sure the place to start is df.groupby('time') but then I can't seem to figure out the right way to use concat (or other function) to build the split data frame that I want. There is probably some simple function I am overlooking in the API.

Comment: Is the frame you want an intermediate step? Having columns named data1, data2 etc is going to make your life difficult later on.

Comment: This is the thing I want to match up with other data. The particular files I am reading are stored with each block of data written in columns. Sure I could do the computation on the `groupby` object, but then I would have to convert the other stuff, the second form I have there into the first. Is there a particular reason why I shouldn't want things in separate columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @PhillipCloud. I assume that this is probably some intermediate step toward the solution of your problem, but maybe it's easier to just go strait to the thing you really want to solve without the intermediat step.

But if this is what you really want, you can do it using:

```
>>> df.groupby('time').apply(
        lambda g: pd.Series(g['data'].values)
    ).rename(columns=lambda x: 'data%s' % x)

      data0  data1
time              
1         2    2.1
2         3    3.1
3         4    4.1
```

Comment: Thank you. Converting it to a series was the step I couldn't come up with. You and @PhillipCloud both seem to think this isn't what I should want. Really it is just two indexed data, earlier code had them as separate columns, but I played with coverting it to using multiindex. Why would I not prefer columns like this?

Comment: @f4hy If this is your end result than you're OK, and you shouldn't worry about the things we said. :) But if it's an intermediate step then it just makes manipulation harder in the future, since you end up with generic column names (which actually represent variables). So you will probably end up stacking the columns into multi-index or melting then into one column or something else... Which could be avoided doing the same thing at the first step. But as I said if this is your final result, then you're OK :)

Comment: Ya, the generic column names are because each column is an independant measurement, literally measurement1, measurement2, and each need to be treated totally independently. using multi index with the first index repeating range(0,20) and the second a simple integer to keep track of which set of 20 it is doesn't actually seem better. If there was a real reason multi index is better, when the second index just needs to be unique but unmeaningful I could switch to it, but this seem to do the job. I was hoping you would have a reason doing it some other way was better.