# How to split a group of related columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I hope to help me. I have a dataframe. It has 2 columns (CONFIRM_STATUS and OUTCOME), the combination of which affects the logical display of the third column (VALUE).

CONFIRM_STATUS has 4 unique values

```
result1 = df['CONFIRM_STATUS'].unique()
result1
array(['CONFIRMED', 'PROBABLE', 'SUSPECTED', 'TOTAL'], dtype=object)
```

OUTCOME has 2 unique value

```
result2 = df['OUTCOME'].unique()
result2
array(['CASE', 'DEATH'], dtype=object)
```

As a result, I have 8 unique combinations that directly affect the meaning of the numeric value of the column VALUE. I need to convert these combinations into 8 columns so that each of them displays one of these combinations. Relatively speaking: death, recovery,...

How can this be done with pandas? I know, it turned out not very detailed, here is a screenshot of these several fields.

```
    EVENT_NAME  SOURCE  DATE_LOW    DATE_HIGH   DATE_REPORT DATE_TYPE   SPATIAL_RESOLUTION  AL0_CODE    AL0_NAME    AL1_CODE    AL1_NAME    AL2_NAME    AL3_NAME    LOCALITY_NAME   LOCATION_TYPE   CONFIRM_STATUS  OUTCOME CUMULATIVE_FLAG VALUE
2752    nCoV_2019   WHO COVID-19 Overview   2020-01-03  2020-01-03  2020-01-03  Authority notification  AL0 RU  Russian Federation  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN Clinical care sought    CONFIRMED   CASE    False   0
2753    nCoV_2019   WHO COVID-19 Overview   2020-01-03  2020-01-03  2020-01-03  Authority notification  AL0 RU  Russian Federation  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN Clinical care sought    CONFIRMED   CASE    True    0
2754    nCoV_2019   WHO COVID-19 Overview   2020-01-03  2020-01-03  2020-01-03  Authority notification  AL0 RU  Russian Federation  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN Clinical care sought    CONFIRMED   DEATH   False   0
2755    nCoV_2019   WHO COVID-19 Overview   2020-01-03  2020-01-03  2020-01-03  Authority notification  AL0 RU  Russian Federation  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN Clinical care sought    CONFIRMED   DEATH   True    0
2756    nCoV_2019   WHO COVID-19 Overview   2020-01-03  2020-01-03  2020-01-03  Authority notification  AL0 RU  Russian Federation  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN Clinical care sought    PROBABLE    CASE    False   0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
4494958 nCoV_2019   WHO COVID-19 Overview   2020-11-22  2020-11-22  2020-11-22  Authority notification  AL0 RU  Russian Federation  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN Clinical care sought    SUSPECTED   DEATH   False   0
4494959 nCoV_2019   WHO COVID-19 Overview   2020-11-22  2020-11-22  2020-11-22  Authority notification  AL0 RU  Russian Federation  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN Clinical care sought    TOTAL   CASE    False   24581
4494960 nCoV_2019   WHO COVID-19 Overview   2020-11-22  2020-11-22  2020-11-22  Authority notification  AL0 RU  Russian Federation  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN Clinical care sought    TOTAL   CASE    True    2089329
4494961 nCoV_2019   WHO COVID-19 Overview   2020-11-22  2020-11-22  2020-11-22  Authority notification  AL0 RU  Russian Federation  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN Clinical care sought    TOTAL   DEATH   False   401
4494962 nCoV_2019   WHO COVID-19 Overview   2020-11-22  2020-11-22  2020-11-22  Authority notification  AL0 RU  Russian Federation  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN Clinical care sought    TOTAL   DEATH   True    36179
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a pandas dataframe into many columns after groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927238/how-to-split-a-pandas-dataframe-into-many-columns-after-groupby)

Comment: Please don't post images of your code 

Comment: @PouyaEsmaeili thank you, but no(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't rebuild your dataframe but you should be able to just create 8 new columns like this example (I only show two). You can get fancier with creating the combinations and building the columns but if it's only eight, just code it simply.

```
df[['CASE_CONFIRMED', 'CASE_PROBABLE']] = ''
```

Once you have  the columns just search on the two columns and set that particular column equal to VALUE.

```
df.loc[(df['CONFIRM_STATUS'] == 'CONFIRMED') & (df['OUTCOME'] == 'CASE'}, 'CASE_CONFIRMED' ]] = df['VALUE']
df.loc[(df['CONFIRM_STATUS'] == 'PROBABLE') & (df['OUTCOME'] == 'CASE'}, 'CASE_PROBABLE' ]] = df['VALUE']
```

If that doesn't work, paste part of the dataset using df.head(15).to_json().